# how to remove decimal value for weight attribute in more information tab in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

[image]

getAdditionalData()) :?>

```
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
    <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('More Information')) ?></caption>
        <tbody>
              <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data) :?>
              <?php if ($_data['code'] == 'weight') {
                $_data['value'] = $_data['value'].'grams';?>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
                  <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_data['label']) ?>"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } else { ?>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
                  <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_data['label']) ?>"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the line like this one :

```
<?php echo str_replace(".000000","",$_data['value']); ?>
```